# Why my Seurat object has gene name as "gene-number"

Tags: seurat

I tried to analyze single-cell RNA sequencing data from PMID: 32849601. I downloaded fastq files. I also made a canine genome reference from https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/assembly/GCF_000002285.3/ according to a guideline from cellranger (https://support.10xgenomics.com/single-cell-gene-expression/software/pipelines/latest/advanced/references#mkref-intro). I ran cellranger count as usual and created Seurat objects using features, barcodes, and matrix files based on the Seurat tutorial without modification.

I found all gene name has the suffix gene "-4" as below. [![enter image description here][1]][1].

Which step should I correct to have a plain gene name without the suffix? Since I have never found this issue before, it's really interesting. Is this related to the step of making a reference genome?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oF1oi.png